# XAMPP - MySQL Shut down Unexpectedly at start in XAMPP control

Tags: php, xampp

**When I open XAMPP control application and click start MySQL button it won't start and it gives me an error. It starts and after a couple of seconds it shutdowns automatically. the errors from the XAMPP control  application is mentioned in below**.

> 12:03:32 PM  [mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL app...
>
> 12:03:32 PM  [mysql]  Status change detected: running
>
> 12:03:34 PM  [mysql]  Status change detected: stopped
>
> 12:03:34 PM  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 12:03:34 PM  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing
> dependencies,
>
> 12:03:34 PM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
> another method.
>
> 12:03:34 PM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and
> check
>
> 12:03:34 PM  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 12:03:34 PM  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 12:03:34 PM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums

**The Following are the errors from my error log**

```
2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Are you sure you are using the right ib_logfiles to start up the database? Log sequence number in the ib_logfiles is 300288, less than the log sequence number in the first system tablespace file header, 300360.

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.



2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

2021-12-21 12:03:32 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

what may cause the problem and how can I resolve them? Thank you in advance

Comment: You have port 3306 taken. Check if another instance or any program is using the same port

Comment: Tried changing the port from MySQL side as well as from XAMPP config settings. But the problem stays unchanged

Comment: Use Windows Task Manager to verify mysqld is running.  STOP it manually and try to start XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I Got it worked. Didn't change the port and kept it default as 3306. Did the following.

1. renamed the `XAMMP\mysql\data` folder to any other name you wish (say `data_old` )
2. make a new folder in `XAMMP\mysql` name `data` and copy all the files in it including `ibdata1`
3. close all running programs and restart XAMPP

No need to copy files from `data_old` but if you do have previously constructed databases then you may copy some files from `data_old`.

Special Thanks for everyone who supported.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is change port to 3307 or other than 3306 from my.ini and edit "\xamppphp\MyAdmin\config.inc.php"add extra line under

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3308;

if u need explaination I've made Youtube video sE2UkEcth0w

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE2UkEcth0w

Answer (score 0):

seems like following error from the message

- Either port is blocked
- Or Application doesn't have enough permission to access those port and serve web application.

### To fix this

- Right click on XAMPP and Click on Run as Administrator
- This will prompt you for password or confirmation.
- Allow by providing password or permission

This will run XAMPP in highest privilege, so you won't be facing permission issue anymore.

If this works, you can do few more step to avoid running as administrator manually every time.

- Right click on XAMPP icon
- Go to properties
- Look for option > Run as administrator
- [*] check the option and save

This will ask for confirmation/password every time when you run XAMPP.

Hope this solves your issue.